# What are the differences between form_for @project_profile and form_for :project_profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I just started to learn rails. My rails version is 3.0.7. I am wondering what are the differences between **<% form_for :project_profile %>** and **<% form_for @project_profile %>**. I have this question because I went into the following situation:

- If I use **<% form_for :project_profile %>**, it doesn't give me an error, but the form is actually not working.
- If I use **<% form_for @project_profile %>**, I will get an error: undefined method `project_profile_path' for #<#:0x00000103546d80>
- If I use <%= form_for @project_profile, :**url** => "/projects/#{params[:project_id]}/profile/update" do |f| %>, it will work but the code is ugly.

---

You can refer to the following codes to understand the context of my problem better.

I have a project model and a project_profile model. One project has one project_profile.

The following two lines are from my *routes.rb*.

```
match '/projects/:project_id/profile/edit' => "project_profiles#edit"
match '/projects/:project_id/profile/update' => "project_profiles#update"
```

This is from my project_profiles_controller.rb

```
class ProjectProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @project_profile = Project.find(params[:project_id]).project_profile
  end
  def update
    @project_profile = Project.find(params[:project_id]).project_profile

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_profile.update_attributes(params[:project_profile])
        format.html {}
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The following code is from **_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @project_profile, :url => "/projects/#{params[:project_id]}/profile/update" do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :title %>
      <br/>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn about resource and nested resource [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) in Rails.

The way you define controller is also not conventional. There is an article on Rails Guides on Getting Started section that [covers that](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model) too.

Comment: Good to know my controller was not conventional. Following the convention helped me to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically spoken, form_for @project_profile is an advanced (resource-oriented), nowadays preferred style. If you want to dig a little deeper into this, the API itself explains the difference pretty well.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

cheers

Comment: In terms of routes.rb, I feel using `resource` is more organized than using `match`.